# New player in Eve Online - accidentally closed the tutorial window

Tags: eve-online

I started a new character, and started tutorial. The game was too slow, so I had to enter the settings screen. But after I returned, the tutorial window is gone and I do not know what to do. The "cancel tutorial" button warns that I would not be able to resume tutorial ever.

So, now already over an hour I am trying to figure out what I have to do. I am at the very beginning of tutorial, it said something that I should find another ship in a window to the right, but what to do next, I have no idea.

Comment: So your question is what? How to restart the tutorial? Where to find an offline version of the tutorial that you can read/work through? Something else?